# iOS Magical record import from array

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

Hi I'm making a synchronise function that update database when receive `JSON` response from server. I want the import only take place if there are different data (new record or update existing record) (To increase performance) (Using `coredata` and `magicalRecord`)

Here is my JSON parser method

```
- (void)updateWithApiRepresentation:(NSDictionary *)json
{
    self.title = json[@"Name"];
    self.serverIdValue = [json[@"Id"] integerValue];
    self.year = json[@"Year of Release"];
    self.month = json[@"Month of Release"];
    self.day = json[@"Day of Release"];
    self.details = json[@"Description"];
    self.coverImage = json[@"CoverImage"];
    self.thumbnail = json[@"Thumbnail"];
    self.price = json[@"Buy"];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MMMM/yyy"];

    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@",self.day,self.month,self.year]];
    self.issueDate = date;
}
```

And my import method

```
+ (void)API_getStampsOnCompletion:(void(^)(BOOL success, NSError     *error))completionBlock
{
    [[ApiClient sharedInstance] getStampsOnSuccess:^(id responseJSON) {

    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
    NSMutableArray *stamps = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [responseJSON[@"root"] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id attributes, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        Stamp *stamp = [[Stamp alloc]init];
        [stamp setOrderingValue:idx];
        [stamp updateWithApiRepresentation:attributes];
        [stamps addObject:stamp];
    }];

    [Stamp MR_importFromArray:stamps inContext:localContext];

} onFailure:^(NSError *error) {
        if (completionBlock) {
            completionBlock(NO, error);
        }
    }];
}
```

I'm getting error

```
CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Stamp' 
2016-08-02 23:52:20.216 SingPost[2078:80114] -[Stamp setOrdering:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78f35a30
```

I have checked my Json parser is working fine. The problem is with my import method. I don't know what wrong with the function. Any help is much appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message clearly describes the exact problem. You do this:

```
Stamp *stamp = [[Stamp alloc]init];
```

But `init` is not the designated initializer for `NSManagedObject` unless you added `init` in your subclass (which you didn't mention doing). You must call the designated initializer, which is `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`. There's also a convenience factory method on `NSEntityDescription` called `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:`. Either of those will work, but calling `init` will not.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help i'm working with Magical Record libary. is the above equal to Stamp *stamp = [Stamp MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];? any way to avoid duplicate when add new record?

Comment: I haven't used Magical Record so I can't be sure.

Comment: So do you know how to avoid adding duplicate record (after receive json response from server) anyway?

Comment: You can either do a fetch to see if any matching records already exist or you can use unique constraints in the data model (which was described at WWDC 2015). Or Magical Record might have something to help with that.

Comment: anyway can we create and array of entity before add new entity (like perform batch adding)?

Comment: thanks, found unique constraint is quite good solution but I still want target OS 7 and above

Comment: Then you'll have to do a fetch to look up matching data before inserting it.

Comment: but i need to create entity first, assign its property by JSON response. Then how to perform fetch and discard if duplicate? for example check for property serverId. Stamp *stamp = [Stamp MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
                    [stamp setOrderingValue:(int)idx];
                    [stamp updateWithApiRepresentation:attributes];

Comment: Why would you need to create the instance without checking? What makes that necessary?